# Why does this closure return function?

Tags: javascript, closures

While watching Learning to Love JavaScript, I got hung up on why this 2nd version wouldn't work. It just returns 'function'. Is a closure not allowed to have a variable directly assigned to it?

```
function getCtr() {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        console.log(++i);
    }
}
var ctr = getCtr();
ctr();
ctr();
ctr();
/* console
1
2
3
*/
/*--------------------------------------
 *   This doesn't work
 */
var ctr = function() {
    var i = 0;
    return function() {
        console.log(++i);
    }
}
ctr();
ctr();
ctr();
/*   console
 *   => [Function]
 */
```

Video Link http://youtu.be/seX7jYI96GE?t=11m12s

Comment: What do you think `return function() {...}` does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It prints that because the function **does** return a function.

Try

```
ctr()();
```

The two forms of function declaration you used have almost exactly the same effect.  Both simply create a function and bind it to a symbol.  All you really changed in the second version is the name involved ("ctr" instead of "getCtr").

That is, if your test had been like the first setup:

```
var actualCtr = ctr();

actualCtr();
actualCtr();
actualCtr();
```

you'll see that it really is the same.

Comment: Nice explanation. You might add that "var ctr = getCtr()" is the same as "var ctrr = ctr()" in the first and second versions. That might enlighten the difference further :)

Answer (score 1):

In your first version, you define a function getCtr. Then you invoke getCtr, keeping the result as ctr.  Then you invoke ctr repeatedly.  You are calling the result of calling a function.

In the second version, you define ctr as your first function, then you invoke it repeatedly.  You aren't invoking the result of invoking the function.

Here's a version of your second code that works:

```
var ctr = (function() {
        var i = 0;
        return function() {
            console.log(++i);
        }
    })();
ctr();
ctr();
ctr();
```